# Weights optimization of a neural network using Genetic Algorithm

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I was told to implement a neural network to do forecasting. So I created a **Feed Forward MultiLayer Perceptron** with a Backpropagation algorithm and it is working fine. But I need to get results faster and faster. So I thaught about **genetic algorithm** t ooptimize the weights in the training session.

How do you suggest to encode the chromosme ?

I already done it as a table of weights generated randomly (-100, 100) but it's not giving extraordinary results. I guess that the problem is that generating a random table of weights limit the solutions space even if the probability of mutation is high.

Any idea how to encode the weights in the chromosme in order to let the genetic algorithm work great ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Faster as in faster convergence? Then use Batch Normalization.

Comment: Using a genetic algorithm will probably require more resources (eg. time and cpu) than just using gradient descent or another analytical learning approach. Have you tried using RMSprop or adagrad?

Comment: I've been working with evolving neural networks before, and I feel that representing the network weights as a bit vector and then perform some transformation between the two representations (bit vector / list of weights) proved to be the most efficient search strategy.

Comment: If backpropagation converges at all, it should converge faster than genetic algorithms because it makes use of gradient information. I would only use a genetic algorithm if backpropagation does not converge.

Answer (score 3):

In short (which has been already suggested in the comments): **don't do this**. Genetic algorithms are a simple metaoptimizers for problems which **cannot be efficiently optimized**, as they are **slow, heuristic** and require lots of **resources**. In particular they should **never** be sued to train a neural network, for which we have dozesns of very efficient training methods (SGD, Rmsprop, Adam). They can be used to optimize some more abstract parts though, like network architecture etc., where one cannot compute valid gradients or even use other well defined mathematical procedures.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use any evolutionary algorithm to optimize neural network weights,
May be better approach is Learning the network once using Back propagation then use the weights maximum and minimum for encoding limits. Lets say weights are distributed between -1.0988333,1.2982293, i would take [-2,2]/(-2,2) so that a chromosome can be generated between in this interval would be more inclined towards better solution and can be optimized further by algorithm. Interval of [-100,100] would be slow in generating optimal solution. Of course, how would you define your fitness function matters in getting optimal solution. One approach would be getting minimum rms value for given weights.