# Problems with teaching a NN using self-written GA

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

So, first of all- what I'm trying to do is write a more or less universal GA for teaching single/multilayer perceptrons.

My understanding is that to achieve that, I have correctly "pick" (optimise) input weights cell, layer weights cell and bias cell. (Please correct me if I'm wrong here)

So far my algorithm:
1) randomly generates the starting population
2) evaluates it by calculating mean standard error
3) selects breeding population and proceeds to next generation by crossovers (crossing over individual weights) and mutation (with mutation step decaying over generations, to make early "search" more widespread, and later adjustments subtle), resulting in a new population that is twice the size of previous one
4) evaluates new population the same way as in 2), and then culls the bottom half of the pack to cut population size back down to initial size
5) repeats all the above until satisfactory error level is reached, or until set amount of cycles passes

The problem is that it never reaches a satisfactory level, even with massive overkills on the amount of computations done (130 population size, 200+ cycles for a single layer network with 10 neurons), and gets stuck on local minima (at least thats what I think is happening, since the results just stop changing) after about 20-30 generations. It is definitely working to a degree, because the approximations plot shape "tries" to follow the expected result, just very poorly. The link below shows the result of trying to teach a 2 layer network with 5 neurons each, to follow the curve of y=x^2 function, given 1000 randomly chosen samples, out of 2000 points along the curve.

http://puu.sh/qrN0z/e53e25a5be.png

Could anyone give me any pointers as to how to tackle this problem?

code: http://pastebin.com/ay2nVmaB

Comment: Please, do not try to train neural nets with GA. This is like trying to sort an array by randomly permuting it and keeping parts which have been sorted - possible, but in general useless overkill while we have plenty of efficient solutions which do the task directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785019/weights-optimization-of-a-neural-network-using-genetic-algorithm

Comment: I realise that using GA to train a neural net is at best sub-optimal approach, but my task is to make an attempt at it to show that it indeed is a bad idea, and then be able to meaningfully compare it to other methods. And if I have to try doing that anyway- I might as well make sure I did it right.

Comment: Show us your code than, as your plot looks a bit odd. You might have some scale issues. Either way start with valid network trained with sgd. Once you have working architecture and code change training to GA, so you are sure issue is not in the neural part. It is also important to keep track of scales of weights etc. As ga can drive your weights to different parts of the space

Comment: Link to code added in main post, I intended to show the fitness over time graphs aswell, but I can only post 2 links. They can be obtained by running the code with matlab. Regarding your last comment, I tried training the neural net with "train" function, using levenberg marquardt algorithm, and it worked without any problems, so it is definitely the algorithm that is not working as it should. As for keeping track of scales of weights, I noticed (after training the net with gradient descent algorithms multiple times) that the weights are always within [-10, 10] so I bound GA to those limits.